# Duplicate mysql update, reduce insert statement

Tags: mysql

I've written a mysql query that update duplicate keys but inserts new keys. The query is too long and I want to reduce it. Is there a way to reduce this query??

```
"insert ignore into nospcampmapping(brand, cam, name, day1, day2, Type)
                  values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                  on duplicate key update brand = values(brand), cam = values(cam), name = values(name), day1 = values(day1),
                  dya2 = values(day2), Type = values(Type)"
```

Comment: Does somebody makes you to pay for each letter used in the query? no? if so, then don't worry about the length of the SQL text. PS. Show complete CREATE TABLE script for your table.

Comment: That's not a long query - is there a reason why you think it is?

Comment: I am writing a query statement using pymysql in Python. It's not the same, but it's because there are several query statements similar to that query, and the code looks complicated. Thank you